# May I use one of the attribute of composite key as foreign key in another table?

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE abc 
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    class VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    division VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    dateOfxyz DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, class, division, dateOfxyz)
)
```

Now, I want to access id class and division part of this primary key in another table as the foreign key, can I do that? and If yes, then how?

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: Foreign keys can be composed of multiple columns, yes.  Is this a syntax question?

Comment: That's easy enough to test.

Comment: No, I am getting an error message (error no 150)

Comment: @Ctznkane525, I agree that  but is it necessary to have same number of attributes in Foreign key same as Primary key ?
Like, PRIMARY KEY (id, class, division, dateofxyz) is primary key
and I want to use FOREIGN KEY (id, class, division) only
Can I do that

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do what you are asking.

Comment: In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem
*In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.*  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TABLE abc
    -> (
    -> id INT NOT NULL,
    -> class VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    -> division VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    -> dateOfxyz DATE NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (id, class, division, dateOfxyz)
    -> );
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'abc' already exists
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t
    -> (id INT NOT NULL,
    -> class VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    -> division VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> alter table t
    -> add foreign key tfk1(id,class,division) references abc(id,class,division);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> show create table t;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t     | CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `division` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  KEY `tfk1` (`id`,`class`,`division`),
  CONSTRAINT `tfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `class`, `division`) REFERENCES `abc` (`id`, `class`, `division`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```